# to bring app to front on receive of a call

Tags: android-intent, android-activity, android

I want to bring my app to front of phone call answer screen when i receive a call. I did every coding part to happen after receiving a call. But the app is not coming to front. Its just open and stays below the phone call answer screen. 
I want to bring my app to front of this screen.
**I did something like below:**

```
Intent i = new Intent(); i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
                    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT);
ComponentName cn = new ComponentName(this, MainActivity.class);
i.setComponent(cn); 
startActivity(i);
```

But there is no change.

Comment: can you place your receiver tag mentioned in your manifest file.

Comment: there is no issue with receiver. Its working properly.. when call receives the app starts. but its not coming to foreground.. that's the  issue i'm facing..

Comment: Did you mentioned any **priority** for the receiver in the manifest???

Comment: No.. i didnt mentioned..

Comment: anyway thanks to all. i found solution for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the **priority** to the receiver..this will help to be called prior than the native incoming call by the android os

```
<receiver android:name="com.companyname.receivers.InComingCallReceiver" >
        <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647" >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
        </intent-filter>
 </receiver>
```

Hope this would be helpfull

Answer (score 0):

You need to Implement one service to invoke application from background.

```
public class LaunchApplication extends Service {

    String PubNubmessage;

    public LaunchApplication() {
        super();

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        super.onCreate();


    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        LaunchApplicationWhenReceivedCall();

        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    private void LaunchApplicationWhenReceivedCall() {
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomeActivity.class);

        intent1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        startActivity(intent1);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

        return null;
    }

}
```

Now start service when your app detects call is received.