# Bring Android app to front of other windows

Tags: android, receiver

I have an Android app that launches automatically when a USB stick is plugged into the phone.  This works well and as expected.

The trouble is, on many android phones, the "My Files" app launches as well when it sees a usb stick inserted.  The "My Files" app comes up after my app, so it covers up my app window.

Is there a way to either bring my app window in front of the My Files window or get it to come up after the My Files window?

I've tried different priority values as mentioned in [to bring app to front on receive of a call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20700446/to-bring-app-to-front-on-receive-of-a-call) but it doesn't seem to help.

The receiver code I am using is:

```
public class MediaReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String TAG = MediaReceiver.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        LogHelper.log(TAG, "Intent received, action = " + action);

        AppEx appEx = (AppEx)context.getApplicationContext();
        if (action.equals("android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED")) {

            if(appEx.isActivityVisible()) {
            context.sendBroadcast(new Intent(BaseActivity.ACTION_STICK_ATTACHED));
        } else {
            Intent i = new Intent(context, SplashActivity.class);
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(i);
        }

        appEx.stickAttached();
    } else if (action.equals("android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_DETACHED")) {
        appEx.stickDetached();

        context.sendBroadcast(new Intent(BaseActivity.ACTION_STICK_DETACHED));
        }
    }

}
```

And, in my AndroidManifest.xml, I have:

```
        <receiver android:name="com.android.myApp.receivers.MediaReceiver">
        <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647">
            <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" />
            <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_DETACHED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```